# how do you add a custom callback javascript param to a bing api callback?

Tags: javascript, callback, bing-api

The bing V2 javascript api requires a callback to work. Using jQuery to add the script block dynamically (ignoring pollution of global namespace):

```
function translate(text) {
    var txt = "text=" + text;
    var lang = "&to=fr";
    var appId = "&appid=apikey"; // Add your AppId here
    var func = "&oncomplete=window.translated";

    $("<script><\/script>")
                .attr("src", "http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/ajax.svc/Translate?" + txt + lang + appId + func)
                .appendTo("HEAD");
}
```

and then using a click event on multiple elements to trigger the translation:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('a').click(function () {
        var tr = $(this).parent().parent();
        var txtin = tr.find('.in').text();
        var out = tr.find('.out'); // would like translation inserted here
        translate(txtin);
        return false;
    });

});
```

and finally the callback required by the api:

```
function translated(text) {
    $("#translation").text(text);
}
```

I want to specify different elements to received the translated text, depending on what element was clicked to kick the translation of - but using the above approach I can't pass any extra params to bing, to then be returned in the callback.

How should I rewrite this to allow a click on el in row1 to put the translation in row1 and a click on an el in row2 to put the translation in row2? i.e. using the element assigned to 'out' in my click event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback method does not support a state object, so you need to keep track of your objects in some global place. I've implemented a queue model to help you make it

1. Add the queue definition in the global variables are

   ```
   var queue = new Array();
   ```
2. Add your 'out' object to it just before calling the service

   ```
   $('a').click(function () { 
       var tr = $(this).parent().parent(); 
       var txtin = tr.find('.in').text(); 
       var out = tr.find('.out'); // would like translation inserted here 
       //Here it goes
       queue.push(out);
       ////////////////
       translate(txtin); 
       return false; 
   });
   ```
3. Append the index of your object to the text and it will be returned back to you as the service does not translate numbers. You can skip adding the index if you are not making more than one translation at a time, this is only to grant that you get the correct object in case of having some service calls slower than others.

   ```
   function translate(text) {

       //Here it goes             
       var txt = "text=" + text + " ___" + (queue.length - 1);     
       ////////////////    
       var lang = "&to=fr";             
       //...no more changes here   
   }
   ```
4. Finally extract your object in the callback method and remove the appended index and the splitter from the translated text.

   ```
   function translated(text) {

       if (queue.length > 0) {
           var splts = text.split(' ___')
           var indx = splts[splts.length - 1];
           var out = queue[indx];
           //remove the out object from the queue
           queue.slice(indx, indx + 1);
           //remove the index number from the end of the word
           text = text.substr(0, text.lastIndexOf(indx) - 4);
           out.text(text);
       }
   }
   ```